# Is there one anti-model that refutes three invalid inferences based on “more than half"?

Tags: logical-deduction

From: Philip Johnson-Laird [BA PhD Psychology (UCL)](https://dof.princeton.edu/about/clerk-faculty/emeritus/philip-nicholas-johnson-laird), Stuart Professor of Psychology Emeritus at Princeton.    (Author isn't  a logician.)    [*How We Reason  (1st edn 2008)*](https://www.amazon.ca/How-We-Reason-Philip-Johnson-Laird/dp/0199551332). p. 224-225.

Is there a single anti-model that can refute 1-3 beneath?

> [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It is not possible.
>
>  Let $n$ be the total number of people. Then we have:
>  $$N_{abc}+N_{ab}+N_{ac}+N_{bc}+N_a+N_b+N_c \le n$$
>  where each $N_*$ represents the number of people with exactly the jobs
>  in the subscript. It is an inequality since there may be people who are
>  none of the three.
>
>  Lets define $N_2 = N_{ab}+N_{bc}+N_{ab}$, and $N_1 = N_a+N_b+N_c$.
>  The above inequality is then:
>  
>  $$N_{abc}+N_2+N_1 \le n$$
>  
>  We are given that more than half the people have each job:
>  $$N_{abc}+N_{ab}+N_{ac}+N_a > \frac{n}{2}\\N_{abc}+N_{ab}+N_{bc}+N_b > \frac{n}{2}\\N_{abc}+N_{ac}+N_{bc}+N_c > \frac{n}{2}$$
>  
>  Adding these three together we get:
>  
>  $$ 3N_{abc}+2N_2+N_1 > \frac{3n}{2} $$
>  
>  To refute conclusion 2 (and 1) we need $N_{abc}=0$. The two inqualities  then become:
>  
>  $$N_2+N_1 \le n \\ 2N_2+N_1 > \frac{3n}{2} $$
>  
>  If we negate the first inequality (which flips its direction) and add it
>  to the second, we get $N_2 > \frac{n}{2}$.
>
>  To refute conclusion 3 we need $N_2 \le \frac{n}{2}$, so it is not possible to
>  refute all conclusions with a single counter-example.